# Transition Probability Matrix and Stationary Distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose that a communications network transmits binary digits, $0$ or $1$. A
message may pass through several links on its way from source to destination, with
the possibility of a transmission error on each link (independently of other links).
If the digit $0$ is transmitted on a link, it is received correctly at the other end with probability $p$, and if a $1$ is transmitted, it is received correctly with probability $q$, $0\lt p,q \lt 1$. Let $X_0$ be the binary digit entering the system, $X_1$ the binary digit recorded after transmission across the first link, $X_2$ the digit recorded after transmission across the second link, and so on.  Clearly $\{X_n\colon n\ge 0\}$ is a Markov chain with 
state space $S = \{0,1\}.$

a) What is the one step transition probability matrix?

b) Find the stationary distribution.

c) If the digit $0$ is transmitted over $2$ links, what is the probability that a $0$ is received?

d) Suppose the digit $0$ is sent, and must traverse $50$ links. What is the approximate probability that a $0$ will be received? (please justify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad a) We have two states, let '$0$' be the first and '$1$' the second one. Assuming such a labelling, the transition matrix is
$$P= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
p & 1-p \\
1-q & q \\
\end{array} \right)$$
as, for example, the [$2,1]$ cell represents the probability of mistake while sending '$1$' message. (i.e. probability of going from state '$1$' to state '$0$' in one step. Still in other words: receiving '$0$' when '$1$' is being transmitted via given link).

Ad b) Since our Markov chain is irreducible and both states are aperiodic, the stationary distribution $\pi=[\pi_1, \pi_2]^T$ exists and is unique. We can find it by solving system of equations $$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} \pi_1 & \pi_2\end{array}\right] \left( \begin{array}{cc}
p & 1-p \\
1-q & q \\
\end{array} \right) =\left[ \begin{array}{c} \pi_1 \\ \pi_2 \end{array} \right]$$ together with $\pi_1+\pi_2=1.$ My computation yields $\pi_1=\frac{1-q}{2-(p+q)}$ and $\pi_2=\frac{1-p}{2-(p+q)}$.

Ad c) It is the question about the probability of going from '$0$' to '$0$' in exactly two steps. Such a scenario can be realized in two ways:

- '$0$' $\to$ '$0$' $\to$ '$0$' which has a probability $\mathbb{P}(\text{'0'} \to\text{'0'})\mathbb{P}(\text{'0'} \to\text{'0'})= p^2$,
- '$0$' $\to$ '$1$' $\to$ '$0$' which has a probability $\mathbb{P}(\text{'0'} \to\text{'1'})\mathbb{P}(\text{'1'} \to\text{'0'})= (1-p)(1-q)$.

Hence, the answer is $p^2+(1-p)(1-q)$. Alternatively, you can compute the $[1,1]$ cell of $P^2$ - two-step transition probability matrix.

Ad d) One can consider $50$ as sufficiently large number of steps to approximate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}p_{11}^{n}$ that is equal to $\pi_1$ (see limiting distribution theorem). Hence, the answer is $\frac{1-q}{2-(p+q)}$.

Comment: thanks for this. would you mind taking a look my other question? it  seems like it is being ignored. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346824/communication-classes-of-a-markov-chain